# C++ - Implementing my own stream

Tags: c++, string, stream, std

*Hello! My problem can be described the following way:*

I have some data which actually is an array and could be represented as `char* data` with some `size`

I also have some legacy code (*function*) that takes some abstract `std::istream` object as a param and uses that stream to retrieve data to operate.

So, my question is the following - what would be the easy way to map my `data` to some `std::istream` object so that I can pass it to my function? I thought about creating a `std::stringstream` object from my `data`, but that means copying and (as I assume) isn't the best solution.

*Any ideas how this could be done so that my `std::istream` operates on the `data` directly?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're looking at actually creating your own stream, I'd look at the [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library. It makes it easy to create your own stream objects.

Comment: And, IIRC, already has the glue for pulling stuff out of a std::vector or an array.

Answer (score 2):

Use string stream:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    char[]  data = "PLOP PLOP PLOP";
    int     size = 13;  // PS I know this is not the same as strlen(data);

    std::stringstream  stream(std::string(data, size));

    // use stream as an istream;
}
```

If you want to be real effecient you can muck with the stream buffer directly. I have not tried this and do not have a compiler to test with, but the folowing should work:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    char[]  data = "PLOP PLOP PLOP";
    int     size = 13;  // PS I know this is not the same as strlen(data);

    std::stringstream  stream;
    stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(data, size);

    // use stream as an istream;
}
```